# letsencrypt certificate with windows / exchange server

Tags: windows, exchange, certificate, lets-encrypt

I try to install and then renew Letsencrypt certificate with Exchange server for owa and activesync. Windows Server 2008 R2 with Exchange Server 2010. (Which will be upgraded to more recent version this year.)

I tried the Win Simple client, but the renewing certificate had a different name and I couldn't automatically change the required bindings.

I found WAT - Windows ACME Tool (https://github.com/lbehm/wat), which says "in-place Certificate renewel doesn't need config changes of IIS bindings".

Installation is pretty straight forward:
.\wat.ps1 domain.example.com -AcceptTerms -Context LocalMachine

I cannot figure out the proper syntax for In-Place-Renewal.

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article may provide some information about LetsEncrypt SSL Certificate and Exchange:

LetsEncrypt SSL Certificate on Exchange 2010
http://www.jsstuff.com/2018/04/letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-on-exchange-2010/

Hope it helps.